# Powerdns не подключается к mysql

Tags: dns, mysql

Всем добрый день! Уже второй день воюю с pdns-server3.1.0-4(debian x64)

```
Jan 21 10:53:50 name pdns[4181]: Our pdns instance exited with code 1Jan 21 10:53:50 name pdns[4181]: RespawningJan 21 10:53:51 name pdns[26515]: Guardian is launching an instanceJan 21 10:53:51 name pdns[26515]: Reading random entropy from '/dev/urandom'Jan 21 10:53:51 name pdns[26515]: This is a guarded instance of pdnsJan 21 10:53:51 name pdns[26515]: Fatal error: Trying to set unexisting parameter 'gmysql-host'
```

Кто может подсказать, где что не так может быть настроено?

листинг pdns.local.gmysql:

```
# MySQL Configuration## Launch gmysql backendlaunch=gmysql# gmysql parametersgmysql-host=localhostgmysql-port=gmysql-dbname=pdnsgmysql-user=pdnsgmysql-password=rootgmysql-dnssec=yes# gmysql-socket=
```

UPDATE1:

```
root@name:/etc/powerdns/pdns.d# lspdns.local  pdns.local.gmysql  pdns.simplebind
```

Листинг pdns.simplebind:

```
launch=bindbind-config=/etc/powerdns/bindbackend.conf
```

Листинг /etc/powerdns/pdns.conf стандартный с установленным пакетом pdns-backend-mysqlс прописанным launch=gmysql

Аналогичная настройка сервера нормально работает на Ubuntu 12.10 Server(x86_64)

Comment: Есть такой файлик  /etc/powerdns/pdns.d/pdns.simplebind.Что у вас в директории /etc/powerdns/pdns.d/ ? И это полный листинг вашего конфига?

Comment: обновил первый пост

Answer (score 1):

комментируем строки в pdns.simplebind и перезагружаем службу... 2 дня мозголюбства.. решение на поверхности... pyatak, спасибо!